# How to get a text character from clicked screen position coordinates where text contains ruby/other tags Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am aware of the method where spans are added to each character and each span has an onClick listener. However, this does not work with text with tags such as ruby or bold e.g.

```html
<p>
    <ruby>漆黒<rt>しっこく</rt></ruby>の<ruby>闇<rt>やみ</rt></ruby>だった。
</p>
```

my current method below turns the above p tag into
`<p>漆黒しっこくの闇やみだった。</p>`

(it removes the tags inside the p element)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(el => {
    let elContent = el['innerText'];
    let characters = el['innerText'].split('');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    characters.forEach(char => {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerText = char;
        span.addEventListener('click', function () {
            let position = 0;
             let el = this;
             while (el.previousSibling !== null) {
                 position++;
                 el = el.previousSibling;
             }
             console.log(elContent + ' : ' + this.innerHTML + ' : ' + position);
        });
        el.appendChild(span);
    });
});
```

is there a way to get some character of text from just screen coordinates like

```js
function click(event) {
  console.log("x:" + event.clientX + "y:" + event.clientY)
  // how can I get the character of text at these coordinates(assuming I did infact click a letter)
}

document.addEventListener("click", click);
```

Edit:
I understand this can also be done with ranges but this is not the purpose of range and is pretty inaccurate.

```js
document.onclick = (evt) => {
  const sel = getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    const targetedNode = range.startContainer;
    const clickedLetter = targetedNode.textContent.substr(range.startOffset, 1);
    console.log(clickedLetter);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I have a solution, I can just loop through the body and add the spans on any character not in a tag

```js
function addSpans() {
    html = document.body.innerHTML
    newHtml = ""
    intag = false
    tags = []
    // add the spans to the relevant characters
    for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
        if (!intag) {
            if (html[i] !== "<" && html[i] !== "\n") {
                newHtml += '<span id="textTag' + tags.length + '">' + html[i] + '</span>'
                tags.push(html[i])
            } else {
                intag = true
            }
        }
        if (intag) {
            newHtml += html[i]
            if (html[i] === ">") {
                intag = false
            }
        }
    }
    // return newHtml
    document.body.innerHTML = newHtml

    // add the event listners
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("textTag"+i).addEventListener('click', function () {
            var id = this.id.replace("textTag", "")
            console.log(tags[id])
        })
    }
}
addSpans()
```